# Guide on using jQuery $(function())

Tags: jquery

The  statement `$(function())` in jQuery is a shorthand for `$(document).ready( ...`

Does it make sense having just once at the beginning of the script portion and holding all the script code (as example within  tags in a aspx page) as needed?

Or rather would it be better to replicate it more than once and containing each set logic of correlated code?

As example:

```
<script>
 $(function()
 {
    //script code for function 1
  });

 $(function()
 {
    //script code for function 2
  });
 </script>
```

Is there any "best practice" about it or are both approaches exaclty equivalent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would get functions off `$(function(){});`

Put there only function calling & doing other stuff.

```
function a(){
    alert('a');
}

function b(){
    alert('B');
}

$(function(){
    a();
    b();
});
```

multiple $(function(){}); calls are very expensive!

[proof](http://jsperf.com/function-usage)

Comment: +1 This is typically what I do also

Comment: Actually in my code I use just one $(function(){ at the beginning, and then inside it, I call the different functions or event calls as needed. Taking the functions body out and placing in separate (external) functions have only order benefit (code is more readable) or also other benefits come?

Comment: I do it too, but it's an example of [temporal coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29#Object-oriented_programming), which is generally considered A Bad Thing.  OTOH, I don't know if multiple `.ready()` calls are even guaranteed to work.

Comment: @Genesis: Thanks for the information. Could you tell me something more on how it would improve performance?

Comment: @Luca: Look at my edit! It eats a lot of resources when you call $(function(){}) multiple times!

Comment: @Genesis: Did not see the edit. Thanks again, now it is much more clear!

Answer (score 1):

Are they ***equivalent***? No, since any variables you declared in one function are not accessible in another.

```
$(function() {
    var a = 3;
});
$(function() {
    $("#foo").text(a); // Undefined
});
```

Most of the time, that doesn't matter, though. And thus most of the time, having multiple calls to $(document).ready() is relatively harmless.

Don't do it repeatedly within a single file just to separate logical tasks. Have a single call to $(document).ready() whose callback calls other functions to handle those individual tasks.

But don't bend over backwards to avoid it either. If I have several files, or several libraries each requiring initialization, I don't hesitate to call $(document).ready() multiple times.